# Am I making use of Polymorphism without knowing here?

Tags: java, android, list, listview

```
List<Lists> listOfLists = db.getAllLists();
```

db.getAllLists() returns a List object.

Am I making use of Polymorphism without knowing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because you don't know (and really don't need to care about) which implementation of `List` interface is returned by `db.getAllLists()`.

More info:

- [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Comment: Awesome! You're explanation has really given me a better insight of Polymorphism.